# Redis keyspace notification when new key created

Tags: redis

I want to know when a new key is created in Redis (which matches a particular pattern to be specific).

The [redis docs give](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) an example of capturing all events on keys, but I don't see a way of actually capturing just the creation of a new key.

When I run the example in the docs and create a new key I only see the operation I performed on that key, not the keys creation itself.

To capture events from the example above I ran:

```
redis-cli -h host -a pass --csv psubscribe '__key*__:*'
```

I see SET events only when I run a SET operation, but I'm running XADD to create the key. I see the XADD operation, but I see every XADD operation with no way to distinguish a new key being generated.

Comment: Don't you get a SET event on the first SET?

Comment: I updated the question. I see SET events, but I'm using XADD to create the keys, I now realized that was an important distinction to make.

Comment: You might want to check the Redis module https://redisgears.io and streamreader https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgears/readers.html#streamreader